# Можно ли частично скопировать структуру одной таблицы в другую?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Можно ли из существующей таблицы взять описание необходимых полей и добавить их в другую таблицу средствами `mysql/phpmyadmin`, чтобы вручную это не делать? Таблицы уже созданы и наполнены данными. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы хотите перенести столбцы с данными?

Comment: Нет, я в одной таблице добавил несколько новых столбцов и хочу такие же столбцы в паре других таблиц создать, но не вручную в каждой, а указать какие столбцы я хочу взять из этой таблицы и добавить в другие.

Comment: Установите Navicat Premium, там есть возможность экспортировать только структуру баз данных

Comment: Структуры у меня есть, ситуация такая: я в одну таблицу добавил несколько полей (5 штук). Но оказалось что точно такие же поля придется добавлять еще в 4 другие таблицы. Собственно вопрос в том как добавить эти 5 полей в другие таблицы простым автоматизированным способом а не руками в каждую?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Штатных средств для осуществления такой операции в phpMyAdmin не предусмотрено. При изменении структуры, вы можете копировать ALTER-запросы к которым прибегает phpMyAdmin. Запрос, который использовался для изменения структуры выводится сразу после успешного выполнения операции. После этого, можно заменить в запросах название таблиц и выполнить запросы в разделе SQL.

Comment: Да, спасибо, так и поступал - весьма удобно оказалось.